# CouchDB timeout when requesting _session

Tags: angular, couchdb, pouchdb

I am using Angular 4 with PouchDB to get data from a CouchDB 2.0 installation. Furthermore I am using the pouchdb-authentication plugin to do the login and signup process.

The login and signup process is working perfectly.

The only thing where couchdb sends me a timeout is when I switch the route in angular (/product/:id) from /product/1 to /product/2 back and forth twice.
On every route change I am sending a request to get the session from couchdb (might not be very intelligent but it should still work) but after going back and forth couchdb sends me a timeout after 10 seconds. In this time I am also not able to access the couchdb interface.
I tried to send the http request on my own instead of using the plugin but that did not fix it.

This is my Auth Service:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    public UserDB;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        public appState: AppState
    ) {
        this.UserDB = new PouchDB(this.appState.get('couchdburl') + 
        '_users', {skipSetup: true});
    }

    public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: 
         RouterStateSnapshot) {
         return this.isLoggedIn();
    }

    public isLoggedIn() {
         return this.UserDB.getSession().then((response) => {
            if ( typeof response.userCtx !== typeof undefined && response.userCtx.name !== null ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return false;
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

These are my routes:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',      component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
    { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'user-management',  component: UserManagementComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'product/:id',  component: ProjectComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  ] },
  { path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent },
];
```

Comment: Submitted an issue on github: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6556

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PouchDB live `sync` API in order to sync local and remote databases, it is possible that you forgot to cancel the live sync on user logout. You might check [here](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html#canceling%E2%80%94replication) to see how it's implemented.

If you're not using live sync, the issue might be due to PouchDB `allDocs()` options. Just set the `timeout` option equal to `0` and see if it can resolve the issue.

Comment: I am using the live option in order to get all new "changes" from the remote database but I am not using replication at all. Furthermore why should Futon timeout until I reload the tab where I would get the timeout for the _session request?

Comment: @Sebi55 Well, `sync` is just a bi-directional replication. Do you cancel your `sync` handlers on user logout?

Comment: I am not using replication at all like I said. I will need to test the timeout for allDocs. Still this should not make Futon timeout at any point from my point of view. Looks to me like a bug.

Comment: @Sebi55 All right. You mentioned you are using `live` option, I thought you mean `live` option of `sync`.